# "Friendly URLs" rule in .htaccess interfering with some directories

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting, clean-urls

My .htaccess is set up to remove .html from URLs as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This is causing problems with the file /help.html, which now gives a 403 Forbidden error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /help/.html on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while 
trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Is there a way to keep friendly URLs and make the help page work?

Comment: I've found one solution: to rename help.html to help.htm.  That's what I'll do if there's no other way to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason why R=302 does not appear in  [NC,L] in the last statement?? As well NC is not necessary for RewriteRule- just RewritCond. And you should have L in [R=301,NC] in the second line.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the changes regarding NC, but why 302 if these redirects are permanent?

Comment: You still need the R which defaults to 301 but you can make it 302 if you want with R=302.

Comment: I understand, but that's not what's causing the problem with help.html--I'd like to fix that first.

Comment: Are there any obvious conflicts such as a help directory??

Comment: Where did you get this code?? Can you give a better explanation of what you are trying to do?? For example: www.example.com/beaver/skin.html becomes what? www.example.com/beaver/skin ? Is this what you are looking for? Also, is help.html in a sub-directory? This code does not look right to me and I cannot get it to do anything intelligent here to give me a clue.

Comment: Yes, there is a file named help.html in root as well as /help directory with one html file in it.  The footer of every page on this site has a link to /help, which no longer resolves after implementing this rewrite rule.

Comment: That may be your problem/conflict. Where did you get your code example (making an assumption here)? This does not seem to be ideal code. Can you provide a link?? I fiddled with this code for a couple of hours before finally giving up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22848/discussion-between-knocks-x-and-closetnoc).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /help 
 RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I added a condition to your .htaccess to check if the Requested URI contains /help ,then it will be passed unchanged to its destination.

Comment: The error message is different now:     "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /help/ on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @Knocksx is this your complete .htaccess or there are other rules also?

Comment: This is the full code

Comment: " You don't have permission to access /help/ " means it tries  to open index.html or index.php and cant find it

Comment: error page are in alias to be served for each virtual host, you need to exclude the errors pages from the rewrite Cond like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !404.htm` then you need to set a default documentto serve a page when you access a path